# React-Native response headers are not being separated

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to get a response header from a fetch post request. However It is jumbling together several headers.

**React Native code**

```
fetch(...).then((response) => {
    console.log(response.headers);
```

**Response**

```
{ date: [ 'Tue, 10 Jan 2017 20:21:54 GMT\nServer: Werkzeug/0.11.15 Python/3.6.0\ntoken: LrPyaQGfL2egGz521TDMUQ==\nContent-Length: 10\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' ],'content-type': [ 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' ] } }
```

This code worked before, but I set up my environment on a new laptop, and all of a sudden this is happening.

I've verified that there are crlf characters in the http response with fiddler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue in the way that [whatwg-fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch/commit/57565a1ba1e563e4424486cb88ea541ac892381b) handlers headers. It has been resolved in whatwg-fetch version 1.1.0 and on. This is a library that react uses.

In order to fix the issue I had to update to react-native version 0.39 and run npm update.

Here's an issue on github with a discussion of the issue I found.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11128